# UTF-8 coded japanese characters don't appear on android display

Tags: java, android, utf-8

i'm trying to code a vocabulary app with android studio. I have a txt file with the vocabulary in UTF-8 format like this.

`akarui         _ あかるい  _   bright`

The Code to read the file and add to dictionary looks as follows:

```
public Map<String, String> adjectives_ej = new HashMap<String, String>();
try {
        InputStream in = am.open("adjectives_utf8.txt");
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            // printout first line
            if (line != ""){

                String[] parts = line.split("_");
                byte[] bytes = parts[1].getBytes("UTF-8");
                String japaneseString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                Log.d("voc", japaneseString);
                adjectives_ej.put(parts[2].replaceAll(" ",""), new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
                adjectives_je.put(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"), parts[2].replaceAll(" ",""));
            }

        }
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(adjectives_ej.get("bright"));
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)        
findViewById(R.id.activity_adjectives);
layout.addView(textView);
```

If i want to see the output of `Log.d("test", adjectives_ej.get("bright"));` i get the error message:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ericwolf.genkiii/ericwolf.genkiii.Adjectives}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

But the `Log.d("voc", japaneseString);` gives me the right output: `07-31 19:42:41.600 25439-25439/ericwolf.genkiii D/voc:  くらい`

Additionally setting `textView.setText(parts[1]);` inside the "while" loop works just fine. So i don't understand the difference here.Is there a problem with saving it in a dictionary?

Comment: Use `Shift-JIS` instead of `UTF-8`. Hope it will solve you.

Comment: sadly not :( same error and the word still does not appear.

Comment: Might be an encoding problem. Can you share `adjectives_utf8.txt` ?

Comment: Does the font contain these characters?

Comment: @selbie https://www.dropbox.com/s/rowbl6cyamk9ewt/adjectives_utf8.txt?dl=0

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes, adding vocabs manually with "adjectives_ej.put("bright", "てすと");" does work

Comment: Are the commands in the right order? Is what you're reaching for in the dictionary already at the logging time?

Comment: Make sure you test with a one line source text file containing just the test line.

Comment: Successfully putting strings in a map doesn't mean the characters exist in your display font.

Comment: @tomas yes it's in the right order. i tested it with only one line. it seems like the value of the dictionary key is a null value and therefore no output.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede ok, but doesn't the font have to exist, because "textView.setText(parts[1]);" printed it on the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the txt file. It looks fine. Although it does contain a BOM, but I don't think that would cause any issues.

It's either one of these problems:

1. Font issue.  Maybe the font you are using to display doesn't support Asian character sets.
2. More likely, the multiple decode/encode from UTF8 and back.  Instead of this:

   ```
           String[] parts = line.split("_");
           byte[] bytes = parts[1].getBytes("UTF-8");
           String japaneseString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
           Log.d("voc", japaneseString);
           adjectives_ej.put(parts[2].replaceAll(" ",""), new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
           adjectives_je.put(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"), parts[2].replaceAll(" ",""));
   ```

Recognize that `line` has already been decoded from UTF8 as a result of BufferedReader. There's no reason to encode it back to UTF8 only to decode it again.  We can also cleanup that `replaceAll` stuff with a simple `trim` call.

So change the above to this:

```
            String[] parts = line.split("_");
            String japaneseString = parts[1].trim();
            String englishString = parts[2].trim();

            Log.d("voc", japaneseString + " : " + englishString);

            adjectives_ej.put(englishString, japaneseString);
            adjectives_je.put(japaneseString, englishString );
```

Comment: Thanks.  Please don't forget to to "accept" the answer (green checkmark) if it worked for you.